# Django. Retrieving and opening a zip file from HDD

Tags: python, django

I have a path to a zip file. I don't know how to

- retrieve the file from the hard drive
  or
- open that zip file. Does anyone know?

The zip file is a zip file, but it's really a .epub file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html

```
>>> import zipfile
>>> path = "example/path.epub"
>>> epub = zipfile.ZipFile(open(path))
>>> epub.namelist()
 ['some_file.txt']
>>> file = epub.open('some_file.txt')
>>> file.read()
```

Comment: Installed Python 2.6.4. Now all of the code above works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need anything Django specific, just use the Python standard library, with the class `ZipFile(file_name[, mode[, compression[, allowZip64]]])` from the [`zipfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html) package.